# How did Skynet become self-aware?

Tags: the-terminator, artificial-intelligence, the-terminator-series, skynet

**How did Skynet actually become self-aware?**

Was it a bug in Skynet's System-core programme, or did the programme simply evolve even beyond the imagination of its programmers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Skynet's intelligence would appear to have been [emergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence). It simply appears as a result of the "*geometric*" increase in its learning power. It definitely wasn't a designed feature (which would qualify it as a bug), nor do any of the novels or films explain in any clear detail *precisely* how it happened.

- **Reese's take on it is quite simplistic.**

  > *“Defense Network computer. New. Powerful. Hooked into
  >   everything — missiles, defense industry, weapons design, the
  >   works — trusted to run it all. **They say it got smart;** a new order of
  >   intelligence. Then it saw all people as a threat, not just the ones on
  >   the other side. Decided our fate in a microsecond. Extermination.”
  >   Reese paused again. He glanced back over at Sarah.*
  >
  > <sub><sup>[Terminator - Official Novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/The_Terminator_(Frakes_novel))</sup></sub>
- **As is the T-800 Terminator's.**

  > ***Skynet begins to learn, at a geometric rate. It becomes self-aware at
  >   2:14 a.m.*** Eastern daylight time, August 29. In a panic, they try to
  >   pull the plug.”
  >
  > <sub><sup>[T2: Official Novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(Frakes_novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: The fools.  If only they'd built it on Windows Vista, this would never have happened on account of it crashing every 5 minutes....

Answer (score 7):

The idea of machine intelligences becoming self-aware predates the Terminator movie - certainly within sci-fi.

There was also a view within the AI research that if you made a system complex enough, you could get emergent intelligence. (you actually need only [very simple rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boids) to get some remarkable emergent behaviours)

In fact, the idea of [Emergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence) is not all that new.

So, SkyNet was simply an incredibly complex software focused on "winning" against the Eastern Bloc (remember, the Cold War was still a thing when this movie came out, and didn't look like it would be ending soon). Eventually, this complexity led to self-awareness as an emergent behaviour, and SkyNet determined that the Communists were not its only enemies.

Anyway -  it's not a bug, it's an (unintended) feature...